# Extracting code as pure string from Roslyn API

Tags: c#, abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Our goal is to build a toy abstract syntax tree for C# classes using Roslyn. We just want to show the basic structure of a class instead of walking through the entire AST. For example (Taken from MSDN):

```
class TimePeriod  
{
  private double seconds;

  public double Hours
  {
      get { return seconds / 3600; }
      set { seconds = value * 3600; }
  }
}
```

Let us only consider the Property `Hours`; we are only interested in extracting the tokens for modifier (`public`), return type (`double`), identifier (`Hours`) as for the body of two accessors we want to directly extract it as a `String`.

However, as we walk though the roslyn (shown in the screen dump) when we get to get accessor's body we did not find the field representing the entire string. What's the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: Looks like you overlooked the obvious... just call `.ToString()` on the AST node :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, seriously, let me try.... thanks a lot! Already wasted nearly half an hour.

Comment: You're welcome, I actually wrote an answer since it turns out there are several methods to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious way is to call `ToString`:

> Returns the string representation of this node, not including its leading and trailing trivia.

If you want the leading and trailing trivia (whitespace, comments, ...), there's `ToFullString`:

> Returns full string representation of this node including its leading and trailing trivia.

For efficiency purposes, you may also be interested in the `WriteTo` method, which writes what `ToFullString` would produce to a `TextWriter`, avoiding intermediate string allocations:

> Writes the full text of this node to the specified TextWriter.